# Once a lock on std::weak_ptr has returned nullptr, can it ever be non-null again?

Tags: c++, c++11

If you take a lock on `std::weak_ptr`:

```
    class foo {};

    auto s = std::make_shared<foo>();

    std::weak_ptr<foo> w{ s };

    s = nullptr;

    s.reset(new foo());

    auto l = w.lock(); // try to get previous foo

    std::cout << "locked: " << (l != nullptr) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
locked: 0
```

Once lock returns `nullptr`, is there ever a condition under which it could return non-null, or is it effectively dead?

My test program suggests once the originally allocated object's reference count is zero then no, `weak_ptr` will always return a nullptr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there every a condition under which it could return non-null, or is it effectively dead?

Well, it's "almost" dead at that point. `lock` calls [`expired`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired) in a way equivalent to this:

```
expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this)
```

Then, looking at the expiration condition:

> Equivalent to `use_count() == 0`. The destructor for the managed object may not yet have been called, but this object's destruction is imminent (or may have already happened).

Either way, there's no possibility for that specific `weak_ptr` to be reassigned to another value.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    shared_ptr<int> p(new int{3});
    weak_ptr<int> w = p;
    p = nullptr;
    auto l = w.lock();
    if (l == nullptr)
        cout << "l = nullptr\n";
    else
        cout << "l = " << *l << '\n';
    p.reset(new int{4});
    w = p;
    l = w.lock();
    if (l == nullptr)
        cout << "l = nullptr\n";
    else
        cout << "l = " << *l << '\n';
}
```

Portable output:

```
l = nullptr
l = 4
```

So yes, if the `weak_ptr` is assigned from a non-empty `shared_ptr`, it can become "reanimated from the dead."

Maybe that isn't what you meant.  But it *is* what you asked.

Comment: As a side note, `w.lock() == nullptr` is not equivalent to `w.expired()` because of `shared_ptr`'s crazy/surprising ability to represent an *owning* `nullptr` as in `std::shared_ptr<int>(std::make_shared<double>(), nullptr)`.

Comment: @ArneVogel Easier: `std::shared_ptr<void> p(nullptr, [](void*) { /* do stuff */ });` Part of the design, even demo'd in [the Boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#techniques_using_shared_ptr_to_execute_code_on_block_exit).